# How to set a value of a cell in google spread sheet using script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this code is not working, I'm not able to set individual cell values from script editor.. here is the code below..

```
function everyyHour() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  //var i = values[1];
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    values[i][10] = 0;
  }
}
```

the 10th column is not getting set to the value 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is changing the `values` array that was populated with data from the spreadsheet, but it never writes it back to the sheet. That is a separate operation that's required.

```
function everyyHour() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  // var numRows = rows.getNumRows();  // I wish they'd never put this in the example.
  var values = rows.getValues();
  //var i = values[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i][10] = 0;
  }
  rows.setValues(values);  // Write the results back to the spreadsheet
}
```